# Sample size for multinomial distribution

Tags: distributions, categorical-data, sampling, multinomial-distribution

Suppose we have multinomial distribution with $k$ outcomes having the same probability $1/k$.  What sample size do we need to guarantee with the probability $95\%$ that $m$ of the oucomes occur at least $t$ times each?

This is a self study.  I am trying to estimate the lower limit of the sample size providing expected frequencies greater than 5 in 80% of the cells of a contingency table.  This is a condition for using  chi-square independence test.

Comment: Nothing remarkable.  I wrote a simple program in Excel counting multiple embeded sums.  I hope, there is an analytical solution.

Comment: OP should really consider reviewing his own question, following these [guidelines](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated).

Comment: @MarceloVentura this question is perfectly fine for CV.

Comment: @Tim Of course the question belongs to CV, but OP could at the very least inform whether it is homework or self study and could include what he have tried so far, among other pertinent possibilities of information to help potential contributor answer, like suggested in the link to CV.Meta I posted above. That is what I meant, in support to first comment.

Comment: @MarceloVentura it is not clear that this is a homework. Sergey Adamov, is it..? If so, please add `[self-study]` tag and read http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: I gets I should have been more to the point in my comment.  Thank you, @Tim

Comment: Are you sure you've paraphrased this question correctly, that your 95% requirement refers to "$m$ of the outcomes" and not to something else, like each $\bar{k_i}$? Because this introduces some complicated dependence. After $n$ observations, if you "come in under $\frac{n}{k}$" counts on one outcome by even **one** observation due to sampling error, this observation is not lost but adds to another outcome, decreasing the liklihood that you would "come in under $\frac{n}{k}$" counts on this other outcome (thus dependence). And if $p = \frac{1}{k}$ can be small$\dots$ also more complicated.

Comment: Yes, I need the probability that each of m outcomes is greater than t.  However, I am fine with any m outcomes out of k.